# UITextView weird margin on top?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a UITextView and it has a weird margin at the top, not sure what's causing this. Here's the picture, the background is orange:

[image]

Here's my relevant code:

```
textViewTest = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 0, 150, 68)];
[textViewTest setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
[textViewTest setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[textViewTest setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[textViewTest setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
//[textViewTest setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:12.0]];
[textViewTest setText:@"Spooky (rename)\nCreated: 4/10/11\nUpload Youtube\nDelete | Favorite"];
```

What I want is the text in UITextView (textViewTest) to not have any space from the top (margin). Currently, there's like 8-10 px from the top of the orange, then the text starts.

Comment: yea it's in a UITableViewCell

Comment: so you want to align the orange view same as the redcolor view?

Comment: What I want is the text in UITextView (textViewTest) to not have any space from the top (margin). Currently, there's like 8-10 px from the top of the orange, then the text starts.

Comment: [This link][1] helped me!! Check it out. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18932245/583344

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you only want to move the text, try

```
[textViewTest setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)];
```

Where a positive number moves the frame towards the middle, a negative moves it out from the middle.

For example, `[textViewTest setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-5, 0, 5,0)]`, will move the text 5 pixels up!

Comment: This solution is good, but why does it happen? For some reason on iOS7 the controls has margin of about 40 pixels for no reason.

Comment: @bashan for the 40pixel margin, you need to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931934/blank-space-at-top-of-uitextview-in-ios-7

Comment: Thanks. I solved it this way. I was just wondering why is that and why is it so hard to control...

Answer (score 2):

In viewDidLoad add:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try sizing your text view to fit its text:
`[textViewTest sizeToFit];`

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to align the orange color view same as the red color view. what is the red color view frame? I think it is the problem of the frame.

why not using the red color view y like

```
textViewTest = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 
                                                            [redView frame].origin.y,
                                                            150, 68)];
```

Comment: What I want is the text in UITextView (textViewTest) to not have any space from the top (margin). Currently, there's like 8-10 px from the top of the orange, then the text starts.

Comment: oh! I guess what you want is vertical alignment. and there is no easy way vertical text alignment in UITextView check this link http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/. Or you can change it to an UITextField and add it to a view. And set the `contentVerticalAlignment` to `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter`