# Blank space at top of UITextView in iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have UITextView with some text in it. Everything was fine with iOS 6 but now with iOS 7 it leaves the blank space on top and then place the text below the middle of the textview.[image]

I didn't set any contentOffSet. 
Please Help!

Answer (score 217, accepted):

A text view is a scroll view. View controllers will add a content offset automatically to scroll views, as it is assumed they will want to scroll up behind the nav bar and status bar.

To prevent this, set the following property on the view controller containing the text view:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

Comment: This is a better answer because it addresses not only how to correct the issue, but why it happens in the first place.

Comment: BTW, you don't have to subclass and override. Just set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO after you instantiate the UITextView.

Comment: @leftspin its a pretty rare case where you haven't subclassed a view controller. And overriding the method means your code will still work on lower iOS versions - setting the property means you need a compatibility check first.

Comment: So if the my Model View Controller is outside UINavigationController the offset would be cleared ? It is kind of crazy... This behavior is ONLY correct when my textview is aligned to the top, otherwise it is rubbish...  Could anybody explain why Apple done something like that ?

Comment: @jrturton apologies for this being an older post and please excuse me as I am new to objective-c but this is currently a property of UIViewController...did it used to be a method?

Comment: @Craig No, it's always been a property, but if you override the getter method then you don't have to check if you're running an older version of iOS before calling it.

Comment: @jrturton thanks for elaborating, I appreciate it. When you said method I wasn't considering a properties getter. Great tip.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with me but I find this: "self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;"
easier to understand than this: "set the property automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets on the view controller containing the text view to NO.". I know they are the same, but...or is it because of the itch to copy and paste? :)

Comment: @GelFermis you're right. The answer originally had some stuff about overriding the property (to make it compatible pre ios7) then it got edited, I've rewritten it.

Comment: Had this problem after embedding a `UIViewController` in a navigation controller in a storyboard. Unchecking "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in IB fixed this issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets ` is deprecated. From iOS11, use [`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior)

Comment: What if i don't want the same behavior on two textView which are in the same ViewController ?

Answer (score 58):

The current answer that IronManGill gave is not a good solution, because it is not based on an understanding of why the problem happens in the first place.

jrturton's answer is also not the cleanest way to solve it. You don't need to override. Keep it simple!

All you need is to set the following:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

in the viewDidLoad method.

Check out the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin

Comment: Make change in storyboard maybe sometimes is better. Go to "Identity Inspector" -> "User Defined Runtime Attributes", and add a definition there.

Comment: `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets ` is deprecated. From iOS11, use [`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior)

Answer (score 46):

In the Interface Builder,

- Select the view controller which contains the UITextView.
- Go to the attribute inspector.
- Uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets."

Comment: This is the easiest solution for my case in ios8

Comment: Note: It's a property of UIViewController. Couldn't find it and then realized I didn't read the text completely

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;  
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

Answer (score 24):

Go to `Interface Builder`:

1. Select `view controller` that contains your `text view`
2. uncheck `Adjusts Scroll View Insets` property

[image]

Comment: this was what I was looking for. also you can do this by adding 'self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false' to viewController

Comment: This is a good and straigtforward answer, that just happened to end my search for "why is this text not showing".

Answer (score 10):

I really wonder if this is a real feature… This 64 point automatic inset is only added when the `UIScrollView` or `UITextView` as the greater deepness of all subviews of the view controller's view. For example, if you add a view behind (here I'm talking about z-buffer, not view imbrication) the scroll view, this 64 point inset is not automatically added.

For example, this one adds the inset:

[image]

In this case, the inset is not added:

[image]

This really seem strange to me… Why would the OS look at the view's deepness to decide whether it should extend the view?

Answer (score 7):

You can delete the blank space on top of your `UITextView` by adding:

```
yourTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Answer (score 6):

On swift (Xcode 6)

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: Do this in `viewDidLoad` of the View Controller with the text view.

Comment: `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets ` is deprecated. From iOS11, use [`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior)

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue by setting content offset to a negative value. Here is Swift code.

```
yourTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -150), animated: true)
```

Comment: This was the best solution keeping the insets and scrolling under translucent bar correctly. I would suggest this modification.

`[self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.f, -self.topLayoutGuide.length) animated:NO];`

Comment: Nothing worked for me except this. Swift, Xcode 9.1.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to understand is that this relates to the navigation bar:

- If your content goes under the navigation bar, you want the view controller to automatically adjust the scroll view insets (default).
- If your content does not go under the navigation bar (you probably used the top layout guide for the top space constraint), you can disable the automatic scroll view inset adjustment like mentioned in most of the other replies.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following trick, it worked.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   self.textView.scrollEnabled = NO;  
}       
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   self.textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Swift 4:

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unprofessional solution, I'm sure... But just putting a blank label behind the textview solves the problem.

Comment: this is not a solution =)

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me (available from iOS 7)

```
[<#your UITextViewInstance#> setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```