# How to align the text in a text view to the top of the page?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextview

I'm trying to set the text to the top of the page in my TextView and I don't know how to align it...
I was looking for a way to do this for a while, please help me to accomplish it

[image]

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the view full screen? In other words, try to enlarge the height under the navigation bar.

Comment: @lootsch hi buddy, it would really help if you will know how to help me here...http://stackoverflow.com/q/22788518/827251 thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enlarge the TextView's height to full screen (under the navigation bar).
This will also add the translucent blur effect for text under the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property to NO on its view controller.

[Blank space at top of UITextView in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931934/blank-space-at-top-of-uitextview-in-ios-7)