# Custom UITableViewCell doesn't show anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have done my homework, I thought I had everything under control.
When I run my project all goes fine, but the `UITextView` in the custom `UITableViewCell`s are empty.

Here is the code that matters:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[NewsCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];
```

And then:

```
NewsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *newsObject = [_newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *title = [newsObject objectForKey:@"newsTitle"];

NSLog(@"title: %@", title); // This puts out the correct stuff

[cell.newsTeaser setText:title];
```

But the newTeaser `UITextView` shows up empty. Why is this and what error have I made?
I should add that this my first time making custom cells in iOS 7...

Comment: If it doesn't show nothing, what *does* it show? Also, make sure that your cell's `newsTeaser` outlet is connected to something like a label.

Comment: Doesn't show nothing? So it does show something ? #doublenegative

Comment: Are you sure the cell.newsTeaser isn't nil ?

Comment: Check if newTeaser is not nil, or its frame is on screen/different than CGRectZero

Comment: @Caleb I have an UITextView and an UIIMageView in the custom cell, both shows up as blank. I have a connection from IB to the custom cell class.

Comment: @Neru It sure is nil, why didn't I think of that? What do I do now? Have I missed a connection or something?

Comment: Yes, you've missed a connection. As I said, make sure that your cell's `newTeaser` outlet is connected to the text view -- that will ensure that it won't be `nil` once the cell is created.

Comment: @Caleb I hope this is enough? http://i57.tinypic.com/2wc0eih.png

Comment: There's nothing there but ads.

Comment: UITextView can have a blank top margin at times.  Make sure you have disabled this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931934/blank-space-at-top-of-uitextview-in-ios-7

Comment: New image then... http://sundsvallbbq.se/connection.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience this often happens because you are implementing the wrong `init` method. Keep in mind that the designated initialiser for a `UITableViewCell` is `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`. If you are adding a custom view hierarchy and you don't do this lazily or inside this initialiser, your views will not be created.

In the case your cells should also be compatible with interface builder, you should also implement `awakeFromNib`.

//EDIT: 
However if you are using interface builder as stated in the comments, you are using the wrong register method.`registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` is only for creation of classes through code. If there is a xib file with your custom cell layout, you need to register that xib file with `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. And if you are using a storyboard, you don't have to register the cell at all. You only need to specify the cell's `reuseIdentifier` in the storyboard file.

Comment: That's possible, but it hardly seems "most likely" in light of the fact that the OP said in comments that `cell.newsTeaser` is nil. Seems far more likely that the outlet simply isn't connected.

Comment: if 'the outlet isn't connected' `[self.tableView registerClass:[NewsCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];` would be the wrong way to register. Anyway, I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching data from an API endpoint, it's possible that your call block is happening on the main/UI thread, so your UI is blocked while waiting for the call block to finish fetching the data.

If that's the case, you need to use dispatch_async inside your block method like this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
```