# Why is the cursor not at the top of the UITextView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, uitextview

The cursor in the UITextView at the top is showing up completely fine, however the second UITextView just below it places the cursor 3-4 lines below it should be. So when I type anything in it, as shown in the screenshot below, it isn't right. The code for this view controller is shown below the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of iOS simulator showing the text in UITextView placed a couple lines lower than they should be]

```
class AddQuestionViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!

    weak var delegate: AddQuestionViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.questionTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        self.questionTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        self.questionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        self.answerTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        self.answerTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        self.answerTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        self.questionTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

    }

    @IBAction func cancel() {

        delegate?.addQuestionViewControllerDidCancel(self)

    }

    @IBAction func done() {

        let item = Question()
        item.question = questionTextView.text
        item.answer = answerTextView.text
        item.checked = false
        delegate?.addQuestionViewController(self, didFinishAddingQuestion: item)

    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if textView == questionTextView {
            let oldText: NSString = questionTextView.text
            let newText: NSString = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)

            if newText.length > 0 {
                doneBarButton.enabled = true
            } else {
                doneBarButton.enabled = false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

        let temp: NSString = textView.text

        if textView == questionTextView {
            self.questionLabel.hidden = temp.length > 0
        } else {
            self.answerLabel.hidden = temp.length > 0
        }

    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {

        let temp: NSString = textView.text

        if textView == questionTextView {
            self.questionLabel.hidden = temp.length > 0
        } else {
            self.answerLabel.hidden = temp.length > 0
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm no IOS developer (just OSX): Check the settings in IB they might differ. Also (OSX) `becomeFirstResponder` is deprecated.

Comment: Checked settings for the both of them. Couldn't spot anything..

This is a strange issue.

Comment: I have experienced this as well the past view days, removing the textview and adding it to the view again (with its constrains) seemed to work.

Comment: Please have a look and the following answer, I think you need this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931934/blank-space-at-top-of-uitextview-in-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a UILabel instead of a UITextView? UILabel tend to "center" the text and not alligning it to the left corner.

Comment: Nope. Happens without the UILabel as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have solved this by now, just in case I'm posting this:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
textView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
```