# Plain text in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I can understand how to remove next padding:

1. I was created Navigation controller (with hidden bar) 
   Add
2. `UITextView` (with blue border)
3. Into `UiTextView.text` add simple text "Вопрос". (red border was added by cmd+hover)

Could you please explain where did this indentation appear? and how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the default padding for elements. If you want to control positioning you will want to get familiar with auto layout. Check out this video:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout
Basically you just need to add constraints to tell it where you want it positioned.

Comment: Thanks for the video tutorial. But is not help me to solve the issue. I found answer at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18932245/1601351

Answer (score 0):

Are you using auto layout? Check the Constant for the Top constraint of your TextView