# Swift: Remove contentInset for UITextView in TableViewCells

Tags: swift, uikit

I am attempting to set the contentInsets to zero for my textView that I place inside my tableViewCells so that I can align my text with the label and imageView bubble. My current implementation looks like this.
[image]

I adopted the solution in this post but does not seem to work for my case.
[Blank space at top of UITextView in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931934/blank-space-at-top-of-uitextview-in-ios-10)

The solution in the above post is for uiviews but mine is in a tableViewCell, which automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is not available in tableViewCell.

Any help here pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `contentInset` to zero will not work since it's applied to `UIScrollView`.

The spacing that you want to remove is actually controlled by `NSTextContainer` inside of `UITextView`.

To remove the spacing just put this in your cell (for example inside `awakeFromNib`):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Removes UITextView inner spacing
    textView.textContainerInset = .zero
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
}
```